# Looking for a word or phrase for realizing a failure only after a long time

Tags: phrase-requests

There is a kind of situation that seems to occur somewhat commonly, that goes something like:

1. Figure out some way to handle a particular situation
2. do it regularly, and make a habit of it, as it seems to work OK …
3. … and only much later actually realize that it very much isn’t OK, that it’s been doing harm all the time, and that it’s too late to fix anything.

Does there exist any good words or phrases for this kind of situation?

Comment: There's the seven Ps - proper prior planning prevents piss-poor performance.

Answer (score 2):

***Dawn on too late***:   *dawn on*, Defined by [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/dawn-on)

> dawn on someone: if something dawns on you, you realize it for the
>   first time

Thus, if something dawns on you too late, you realize it, but it but it is too late to do anything about it.

"As she was being prepped for a quadruple bypass, it dawned on her, but too late, that fast food three times a day for thirty years had not been a good idea, however much she hated cooking."

Answer (score 1):

**That's the way the cookie crumbles**

> 1. NORTH AMERICAN informal that's how things turn out (often used of an undesirable but unalterable situation).

from google.

Answer (score 1):

[Twenty-twenty hindsight](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9QuEiIMaBt0C&pg=PA477&lpg=PA477&dq=hindsight%20idiom&source=bl&ots=fHJUpExO27&sig=KFjBNiMI89LoaIwqFnodhr93gU8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw6PrOqYrMAhVHWxQKHX8kBBM4ChDoAQgfMAI#v=onepage&q=hindsight%20idiom&f=false) (American English idiom, dating from the first half of the 1900s):

knowledge after the fact, as in:

> *'With twenty-twenty hindsight, I wouldn't have bought these tickets.'*

This idiom uses *twenty-twenty* in the optometrist's sense, that is, 'indicating normal vision' and *hindsight* in the sense of 'looking back' or 'reconsidering'.

Source: The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms. 2nd edn. 2013

Answer (score 1):

***no use closing/shutting the stable*** (or [***barn***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22closing+the+barn+door+after%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=ay0OV4X7KcSfsgGpkLfICg)) ***door after the horse has bolted***; [***no use locking the stable door after the horse is stolen***](https://books.google.fr/books?id=9QuEiIMaBt0C&pg=PA275&dq=%22locking+the+stable+door+after%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUtOStvovMAhXFKiwKHVqNBnQQ6AEIWTAH#v=onepage&q=%22locking%20the%20stable%20door%20after%22&f=false)

> closing/shutting the stable door after the horse has bolted
>
> trying to stop something bad happening when it has already happened and the situation cannot be changed: *Improving security after a major theft would seem to be a bit like closing the stable door after the horse has bolted.*
>
> [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/closing+the+stable+door+after+the+horse+has+bolted)

***If wishes were horses, beggars would ride***; ***if ifs and buts were pots and pans, there'd be no work for tinkers*** (or ***tinkers' hands***); ***if ifs and buts were candy and nuts, it'd be Christmas everyday***

> If you could achieve your aims simply by wishing for them, life would be very easy.
>
> *"I wish it didn’t have to be that way." "If wishes were horses," David sighed.*
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&q=if+wishes+were+horses&oq=if+wishes+&gs_l=tablet-gws.1.0.0l3.1999.6792.0.11844.11.8.0.3.3.0.406.1487.0j1j2j1j1.5.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..3.7.1211.0.is1PQY-7v4k)

Answer (score 0):

***[It's no good/use crying over spilt milk,](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/It%27s+no+use+crying+over+spilt+milk)***  also ***there's no point crying over spilt milk*** are close to what you are describing:

> - something that you say which means you should not get upset about something bad that has happened that you cannot change.

(TFD)

Answer (score 0):

Synecdochically (and somewhat facetiously): [petrochemistry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrochemistry).