# The dog started barking after the thief had left the place six months ago

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, idiom-meaning, metaphors

> **It is like a dog barking six months after the thief  left**.

*This  is an  Indian Idiom and is used when someone fails to do their duty at the right time and makes unnecessary fuss very late after the dangerous event happened long ago.*

I believe that the question about the idiom has not been asked earlier.

I would like to know an almost equal idiom in English.

This is not at all a duplicate of the previous post and even the answers do not solve my problem. The previous post asked for something that means one needs to make a habit of doing things regularly otherwise they fail to  do things at the right time.

Dog stands for faithfulness but rarely fails to bark at a thief instantly but it surprisingly not only failed to do its duty but barked unnecessarily after the thief left the place long ago which is inexcusable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for a word or phrase for realizing a failure only after a long time](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319156/looking-for-a-word-or-phrase-for-realizing-a-failure-only-after-a-long-time). (Don't be put off asking future questions, it's not easy to find)

Comment: My first thought was "Shutting the barn door after the horse has bolted," which was one of several good answers at the link @TimLymington mentioned. The parallel idea to your Indian idiom as that a protective action is performed too late, and only after an unfortunate event happened.

Comment: You might be surprised to hear that saying that the dog was barking "after the thief left a long time ago" is actually ungrammatical in English. I leave it to our sister size for [ell.se], or others here, to explain just exactly why.

Comment: @ tchrist. shall  I  ask the  question (The  dog  barked)  on  this  site?  Nobody   has  responded to  your  question  so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of phrases come to mind to capture the idea of ineffective actions that happen long after a time when they could have been useful:

***Too little, too late*** - this suggests that someone's efforts are halfhearted and not timely enough to be of any practical use. Their effort is not sufficient to accomplish anything (too little), and it's happening after a time when it might have helped (too late).

***A day late and a dollar short*** - this also suggests that a person is too late and ill-equipped for some particular task or event. There's a slight connotation of lack of intention here, as the person may be surprised to find that they are too late/ill-equipped.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit like: "trying to close the stable door after the horse has bolted."

This expresses a similar sentiment; the action of the individual is appropriate, just not at the right time.

This idiom is independent of the risk or danger associated with the event; it could apply equally to something annoying or life-threatening.